# How to display article's tags from Victoire?

Tags: symfony, twig, victoire

I would like to display the `tags` associated to an `Article` from a [`Blog`](https://github.com/Victoire/victoire/tree/master/Bundle/BlogBundle) managed by [Victoire](https://github.com/victoire/victoire).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by using the [render widget](https://github.com/Victoire/WidgetRenderBundle).

#### Create a render_tags.html.twig file:

```
{# Resources/views/Article/render_tags.html.twig #}
{% if tags is not empty %}
    <ul>
        {% for tag in tags %}
            <li>{{ tag }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

#### Create a rendering method in your controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/renderArticleTags/{id}", name="app_render_article_tags")
 * @Template("Article/render_tags.html.twig")
 */
public function renderArticleTagsAction(Article $article)
{
    $tags = [];

    /** @var \Victoire\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag $tag */
    foreach ($article->getTags() as $tag) {
        $tags[] = $tag->getTitle();
    }

    return [
        'tags' => $tags,
    ];
}
```

#### Add the widget and configure it:

In tabs *Article* > *Current entity*:

- Route: `app_render_article_tags`
- Parameters: `{"id":"{{entity.id}}"}`